# Powershell, download CSV into string

Tags: powershell-4.0

In Powershell, instead of downloaded a CSV file to drive from a web request, can you download a file directly into a string?  I often pull earthquake data from the USGS database which outputs the data as a downloadable CVS file.  The issue is data is pulled per day and when pulling years of data I end up pulling a thousand or more files, then pipe them together.  If I can download directly into a string I could eliminate the read write file time needed for a thousand or more files by doing it all in memory.

The basic portion of code used to pull the file is:

```
$U = $env:userprofile          
$Location = "Region_Earthquakes"
$MaxLat = "72.427"
$MinLat = "50.244"
$MaxLon = "-140.625"
$MinLon = "-176.133"
$yearspulled = 1
$ts = New-TimeSpan -Days 1
$Today = Get-Date
$StartDate = [datetime](((Get-Date -format "yyyy") - $yearspulled + 1).ToString() + "-01-01 00:00:00")

While ($StartDate -le $Today)
{$EndDate   = $Startdate + $ts
$Start = $StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
$FileDate = $StartDate.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")
$End = $EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
$url = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query.csv?starttime=$Start&endtime=$End&minmagnitude=-1.00&maxmagnitude=10.00&maxlatitude=$MaxLat&minlatitude=$MinLat&maxlongitude=$MaxLon&minlongitude=$MinLon&eventtype=earthquake&orderby=time"
$output = "$U\DownLoads\$Location" + "_$FileDate.csv"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)
Write-Output "Date pulled for $Start"
$Startdate = $Startdate + $ts}
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient). The `System.Net.WebClient` class has a method [`DownloadString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring) that does exactly what you're asking.

> ## WebClient.DownloadString Method
>
> Namespace: System.Net
>   Assemblies: System.dll, netstandard.dll, System.Net.WebClient.dll, System.Net.dll
>
> ***Downloads the requested resource as a String.*** The resource to download may be specified as either String containing the URI or a Uri.

Emphasis mine.

```
$s = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)
```